# How to know with xuggle a video is a flash video?

Tags: java, xuggle

If I look the property of a flash video by right clicking and selecting property, it tells me that this video is:

> Type: Flash video (video/x-flv)

I really would like to have the same result in java library that I am using called xuggle.

How can I identify all flv videos with xuggle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First we create a Xuggler container object:

```
IContainer container = IContainer.make();

// open the video 
container.open("myvideo.flv", IContainer.Type.READ, null);
```

This will return short name like "flv":

```
String myvideoFormat = container.getContainerFormat().getInputFormatShortName();
```

This will return the long name:

```
String myvideoFormat = container.getContainerFormat().getInputFormatLongName();
```